# Cant find the name of the Android's small dialog box component and how to implement it on React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to recreate this small and discrete dialog box on the image below using React Native. I can find this component when I set an Alarm or copy some text to clipboard on my Android Phone. But I couldn't discover its name to start some research.

[image: clock app showing a small and discrete dialog box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the Toast in Android which is available in react-native

You can refer the docs here
https://reactnative.dev/docs/toastandroid

The out of the box feature of React Native is only available in Android

If you want to use this in IOS and Android you can use a library like below.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-toast